# how to connect react-native to android studio

Tags: react-native

The android simulator opens but it does not display anything

```
npm run android

> hello@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info Starting JS server...
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.IOException: La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de r�pertoire ou de volume est incorrecte

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.IOException: La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de r�pertoire ou de volume est incorrecte

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s

    at makeError (C:\Users\jawhar\Desktop\First_React\hello\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\jawhar\Desktop\First_React\hello\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\jawhar\Desktop\First_React\hello\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\jawhar\Desktop\First_React\hello\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: Have you viewed React Native's docs on setting up your environment? Link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: I did, but in result

Comment: yes but not result

Comment: So you've basically created the environment according to the docs and ran "npx react-native run-android" inside a new project and got this error?

Comment: yes absolutely :)

Comment: I think I know what's happening here.. this comment: "java.io.IOException: La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de r�pertoire ou de volume est incorrecte", you are out of space my friend, and I think it's not your fault. I sometimes get this error, what you need to do is increase the storage: go to Android Studio(if you are in a project, quit it so you will have the menu only) -> Pick the three dots and choose Virtual Device Manager -> Edit AVD -> Show Advanced Settings -> Pick "No SDCard" and make Internal Storage at least 2000MB

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what's happening here.

This message:

```
java.io.IOException: La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de r�pertoire ou de volume est incorrecte
```

**You are out of space my friend**, and I think it's not your fault.

I sometimes get this error too and it happens because Android Studio sets the size of the emulator by default to pretty low storage.

**You need to increase the storage emulator's taking:**

1. Enter Android Studio (if you are in a project, quit it so you will have the menu
   of IDE only)
2. Pick the three dots
3. Choose Virtual Device Manager
4. Edit AVD
5. Show Advanced Settings
6. Pick "No SDCard" and make Internal Storage at least 2000MB

Cheers